# How to wake up an app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

Is it possible to wake up an app every `x` minutes, so that the application can do something in the background? So the app stays in the background.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This doesn't wake an app up every x minutes, but will launch an app into the background:

An app can be woken by a significant location change, if the app has indicated that it wants to monitor such events.

See: [CLLocationManager Docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/CLLocationManager/CLLocationManager.html#startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges)

Look for a method called `startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges`. If a significant location change occurs while your app is not in the foreground or isn't running at all, your application will be launched in the background, allowing the app to perform background-only operations (e.g. no view code will run).

Answer (score 7):

No, such behavior is not supported by the iOS SDK.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot wake your app programmatically.  You could incorporate push notifications; however, the user would have to opt to open the notification.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can use internal (like reminder) or external (push) notification to to open an app. however, the user would have to opt to open the notification.